# No "Undefined offset" if array is NULL

Tags: php

I'm not sure this is a bug, so can anyone tell why does not php show a notice if you try to access a key which is not defined of an array that is NULL? Documentation says

```
Converting NULL to an array results in an empty array.
```

So accessing a key that is not defined must generate notice.

```
<?php

$a = NULL;
echo $a['1'];

$a = array();
echo $a['1'];
?>
```

Prints out ony

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/shared/1.php on line 14
```

Thank you for your help.

---

Edit: I take the liberty of adding another example script to the question

```
<?php
$a = NULL;
var_dump('line '.__LINE__, $a['1']);

$a = array();
var_dump('line '.__LINE__, $a['1']);
```

which prints

```
string(6) "line 3"
NULL

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in [...]/test.php on line 6
string(6) "line 6"
NULL
```

Comment: You're not converting NULL to an array; you're treating it as a string when you're trying to access the character at offset 1

Comment: @MarkBaker: That's what I thought too, but... `var_dump($a['1'])` => `NULL`.

Comment: Quoting from the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr): `Characters within strings may be accessed and modified by specifying the zero-based offset of the desired character after the string using square array brackets, as in $str[42]. `

Comment: It seems to me the answer is simply "well, the `null` is not converted to anything -- simply indexing into `null` always returns `null` no matter the index you use". Why? Because PHP. But the source is too convoluted for me to back this up with facts.

Comment: @MarkBaker: which would be the same problem: the OP would expect a `PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 1 in ...` error in that case. Which isn't triggered either.

Comment: While I'm sure there's a reason why it works the way it works, this reason my not be on purpose (i.e. nobody decided it should work that way, it simply does because the source code is written the way it is) and should mostly not matter because this is a nonsensical and therefore mostly undefined operation to begin with. *Should* it behave differently? Probably so. *Why doesn't it?* Because reasons.

Comment: @deceze: Looks like its a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64194).

Comment: @Amal If only tentatively... :)

Comment: @Jon It's not just `null` ... `$a = 123; var_dump($a[1]);` will give you the same ... surprise! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you dereference a variable as an array (for reading), the virtual machine will internally call [`zend_fetch_dimension_address_read`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_execute.c#1249), which in turn loads the right value into the result variable, depending on the type of variable you're trying to dereference.

In the case of `null` (and int / float / bool), it will choose [this branch](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_execute.c#1261):

```
case IS_NULL:
  result->var.ptr = &EG(uninitialized_zval);
  PZVAL_LOCK(&EG(uninitialized_zval));
  return;
```

Whereby `EG(uninitialized_zval)` is basically the `null` itself; no notices are raised when this happens. As Amal has pointed out, there's a [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64194) for this behaviour, but not much has been done about it for almost a year.

> Documentation says "Converting NULL to an array results in an empty array."

An array dereference doesn't convert something into an array (unless you use `[]` or use it in a write context). The conversion that the manual speaks of is most likely an array cast:

```
var_dump((array)null);
// array(0) { }
```

#### Update

After digging into the system a little more, I found that this (partially) makes the following construct work:

```
$list = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
while (list($key, $value) = each($list)) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
```

When the end of the array is reached, `each()` returns `false` and so internally `false[0]` and `false[1]` are evaluated before the `list()` expression itself yields `false`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this was actually reported as  [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64194).  Here's what I found in the comments section (description adjusted to match your variable names):

Your code:

```
$a = NULL;
echo $a['1'];

$a = array();
echo $a['1'];
```

Here, the variable `$a` is initially declared as a variable of type `NULL`.
`$a` is initially declared as `NULL`.

In the first echo statement, the attempt to reference an index of `1` in `$a` is effectively ignored: the variable is not an array to begin with.

`$a` is then cast into an array. (`$a = array();`)

In the second echo statement,`$a` is an empty array, which PHP can enumerate against and ultimately determine that index `1` is **not** present.

Hence the first echo results in a NULL output, whilst the second results in PHP issuing an E_NOTICE.