# What is the role of uninitialized_zval in the PHP kernel?

Tags: php, php-7, php-internals

uninitialized_zval appears in multiple places in the PHP kernel, but I don't know what it does. For example, in the ZEND_ASSIGN_DIM_SPEC_CV_UNUSED_OP_DATA_CONST_HANDLER handler:

```
            variable_ptr = zend_hash_next_index_insert(Z_ARRVAL_P(object_ptr), &EG(uninitialized_zval));
```

Why use uninitialized_zval? And when will use uninitialized_zval?

Comment: uninitialized_zval is equal to null as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456583/no-undefined-offset-if-array-is-null